# Copy sheet data to the end of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I am able to copy the last row of one workbook and paste it after the last row of another workbook. I want to copy the entire data from row 2 (row 1 is header) in the first workbook and paste it after the last row of another workbook. Please advise me what changes are required in the code below to copy the entire data from row 2 instead of only the last row.

```
Dim lastS1Row As Long       
Dim nextS2Row As Long       
Dim lastCol As Long         
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lCol1 As Long
Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet, s2Sheet As Worksheet
Dim source As String        
Dim target As String        
Dim path As String
Dim path1 As String

    source = "Students"     'Source Worksheet Name
    path1 = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book17.xlsx"
    path = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book16.xlsx" 
    target = "Students" 'Target Worksheet Name

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled    


    Set s1Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(source)
    Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path1).Sheets(target)   

    lastS1Row = s1Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    nextS2Row = s2Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastCol = s1Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  

    For lCol = 1 To lastCol
        s2Sheet.Cells(nextS2Row, lCol) = s1Sheet.Cells(lastS1Row, lCol)
    Next lCol
    Next lCol1 

    s2Sheet.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    s1Sheet.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Please update the formatting of your code as it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

This adjusted version of your code should do the job:

```
Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet, s2Sheet As Worksheet
Dim source As String
Dim target As String
Dim path As String
Dim path1 As String
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngTargetStart As Range

    source = "Students"     'Source Worksheet Name
    path1 = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book17.xlsx"
    path = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book16.xlsx"
    target = "Students" 'Target Worksheet Name

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Set s1Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(source)
    Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path1).Sheets(target)
    Set rngSource = Range(s1Sheet.Range("A2"), s1Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    Set rngTargetStart = s2Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    rngTargetStart.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value

    s2Sheet.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=True
    s1Sheet.Parent.Close
```

I removed something what seemed unnecessary. The main thing is that now you don't loop through columns and rows. Now you can do it with one operation.

Avoid as much as you can things like `.Select`, `.Activate`. and `.Copy` if you just need values to be pasted. You can simply do something similar like I did:

```
Target.Value = Source.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set `s1Sheet` and `s2Sheet` I think you should be able to use these 2 lines to copy & paste the entire range at once:

```
    'copy Cells A2 through last row and last column used
    s1Sheet.Range(s1Sheet.Cells(2, 1), s1Sheet.Cells(s1Sheet.Cells(s1Sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
    s1Sheet.Cells(1, s1Sheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy

    'paste those cells in next blank row of second sheet
    s2Sheet.Cells(s2Sheet.Cells(s2Sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'Here you go:

Range("A2").End(xlDown).select
selection.End(xlRight).select
selection.copy
'then active the next sheet for e.g Sheet2.Active
last_row = range("A1048576").end(xlup).row
range("A" & last_row).paste

' Done
```

Comment: Can you please provide me complete coding. I am not sure as to where to put the revised coding in my programe

Comment: My apology, I am getting error. Please provide me complete code

Comment: Below coding is shwoing error With s1Sheet
Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlRight).Select
Selection.Copy
End With

'then active the next sheet for e.g Sheet2.Active
With s2Sheet

last_row = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & last_row).Paste

End With

Comment: Avoid `.Select`, as this is a drag on performance. You can simply do this: `Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlRight).Copy`. But be aware, as this would only copy one cell and you cannot be sure that it's the last cell in the sheet - if you had any blank cells in the Column A or on the last row, this would point to another cell and not the last cell.

Comment: Also, older Excel versions do not have `range("A1048576")`. It's always better to do something like `Range("A" & Rows.Count)`.